# Get map value in EL by key containing quotes

Tags: jsp, hashmap, escaping, el, quotes

I am passing list of maps to JSP from spring controller. Inside foreach loop I am trying to get value inside map using key which contains quotes in the following way:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${account["TO_CHAR(openingdate,'YYYYMMDD')"]}" ... />
```

However, I am getting syntax error. Please advise if anyone has come across this issue.

NOTE: I can't change map keys as it is returned from database like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quotes for EL strings when the attribute itself is double quoted (or the other way round) and inner quotes should be escaped.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${account['TO_CHAR(openingdate,\'YYYYMMDD\')']}" ...  />
```

Note that the syntax highlighter here has also become happy.

If this still fails, then your EL implementation has likely the bug that it requires a second slash to escape the slash itself (older Apache EL is known to have this trouble, but Oracle EL not). Re-escape the slash itself then.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${account['TO_CHAR(openingdate,\\'YYYYMMDD\\')']}" ...  />
```